# Error 5407: Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval inside stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I have searched for this type of error Teradata Error "5407 Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval" here and online but could not find any solution.

Simply put: I have a simple sproc in Teradata which has 2 inputs and one output.  Here is the sproc:

```
Replace PROCEDURE SP.CompUserReturnID (
   IN NTIDVar varchar(50),
   IN CreatedDate TIMESTAMP(6),
   OUT ReturnRes integer
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE res varchar(1000);

    DECLARE RetCompID integer;
    DECLARE ReplaceNTIDVAR varchar(50);

    -- In some cases, the NTIDVar contains the single quote (').  Example:   John'O.Smith@company.com
    -- so we need to replace the single quote
    set ReplaceNTIDVAR = oreplace(NTIDVar,'''','''''');

    set res = 'INSERT INTO tables.Computer (NTID, CreatedDate) VALUES (''' || ReplaceNTIDVAR || ''',' || CreatedDate ||') ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE res;

    -- Do something else
    set ReturnRes = res;

    end;
```

When executing this simple sproc, I get the error message:

> Teradata Error 5407 Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval

The CreatedDate column is define inside TD tabble as TimeStamp(6).

Any clue would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by this part, `|| CreatedDate ||`. Concatenation needs string operands, but `CreatedDate` is a timestamp and there are no automatic type casts for time and timestamp.

When you add an explicit `|| CAST(CreatedDate AS VarChar(26)||` you'll get another error, because the string you pass to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` must be valid syntax, but you try to execute:

```
INSERT INTO tables.Computer (NTID, CreatedDate) VALUES ('bla',2018-05-03 12:25:41.65000)
```

So you need to quote the timestamp (and better use a timestamp literal):

```
SET res = 'INSERT INTO Computer (NTID, CreatedDate) VALUES (''' || ReplaceNTIDVAR 
          || ''', TIMESTAMP ''' || Cast( CreatedDate AS VARCHAR(25))  ||''') ';
```

which finally results in valid syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Computer (NTID, CreatedDate) VALUES ('bla', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-03 12:27:34.99000')
```

BUT, there's no reason for Dynamic SQL (which is prone to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), simply use a hard-coded insert with parameters:

INSERT INTO Computer (NTID, CreatedDate) VALUES (:NTIDVar, :CreatedDate);

Of course, your final `SET ReturnRes = res;` will also fail, because `ReturnRes` is an INT.

Comment: Great explanation.